# Chrome.downloads: Identify which windowId or tabId has initiated a download

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use the Chrome extension API or Chrome DevTools API to determine which windowId or tabId has triggered the download event? Or are there any workarounds to determine the initiator that use different functions (maybe using webRequests)?